# Build List from binary tree inorder traversal using function "fold"

Tags: scala, binary-tree, higher-order-functions

I'm learning Scala. Now I have this code snippet:

```
sealed abstract class BSTree {
    def fold[A](init: A)(f: (A, Int) => A): A = this match {
      case Empty => init
      case Node(left, data, right) =>
        val curInorder:A = f(left.fold(init)(f), data)
        right.fold(curInorder)(f)
    }
}

case object Empty extends BSTree
case class Node(left: BSTree, data: Int, right: BSTree) extends BSTree
```

My aim is to add another method toList in `class BSTree`, which is on top
of method `fold` and build a `List` from the binary tree's inorder traversal.

My current implementation is:

```
sealed abstract class BSTree {
    def fold[A](init: A)(f: (A, Int) => A): = .....//code snippet skipped
    def toList: List[Int] =  
             fold(Nil: List[Int])((xs: List[Int], hd)=> hd::xs).reverse
}
```

But I feel that building a `List` and then reversing it is ugly. Is there a more elegant approach?
Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: no, it's not ugly. Pretty standard actually. Then again, you can always right `foldRight` ...

Comment: You may want to consider this: `def toList: List[Int] = fold(ListBuffer[Int]())((acc, data) => acc += data).toList` Note that `ListBuffer`'s `+=` and `toList` are of time complexity O(1).

Comment: I don't think using a mutable structure is any improvement over reversing the result in the end.

Comment: `ListBuffer.toList` saves list traversal and memory allocation caused by `List.reverse`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your fold is not tail recursive which for large input might result in `StackOverflowException`. I'd encourage you to try out and implement it on your own using `Stack`. For reference I'll place a sample implementation at the bottom of my post.

Secondly, as it was already mentioned in comments - you might want to use `ListBuffer` so that building your list is more efficient in reversed order (thus, there is no need to reverse it back).

Here's a one-liner:

```
def toList: List[Int] = fold(ListBuffer.empty[Int])(_ += _).toList
```

And the the reference for implementing tail-recursive `fold`:

```
def fold[B](init: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
  def go(stack: List[(A, Tree[A])], current: Tree[A], acc: B): B = (current, stack) match {
    case (Empty, Nil) => acc
    case (Empty, (d, r) :: xs) => go(xs, r, op(acc, d))
    case (Node(l, d, r), _) => go((d, r) +: stack, l, acc)
  }

  go(Nil, this, init)
}
```

Comment: I don't think using a mutable structure is any improvement over reversing the result in the end.

Comment: @Dima I would never ever expose mutable API in Scala but when it comes to cases where I can easily improve performance of my code using a mutable structure I'd definitely go for it as it's just a local thing.

Comment: @Dima, in the implementation above, greenshade calls ListBuffer#toList, grabbing an immutable snapshot, before returning. The reference to the mutable ListBuffer is lost after returning. I don't see a leak. If I'm simply missing something, then please point it out. Otherwise, what's the danger? I see this in idiomatic Scala all the time. The important thing is obeying the method signature, and returning an immutable copy, and not letting the local mutability leak.

Comment: @FriedBrice you are correct, there is no leak. But there is no improvement, performance or otherwise over using an immutable list. It is better to use immutable containers even when you are not leaking them (that's why you don't want to leak them in the first place). In this case, there is no reason to introduce mutability into logic.

Answer (score 1):

I find that simply using `xs :+ hd` instead of `hd::xs` puts the values in the correct order (depth-first, left-to-right).

```
val testTree: BSTree =
  Node(Node(Empty, 0, Empty), 1, Node(Empty, 2, Node(Node(Empty, 3, Empty), 4, Empty)))

def toList(bSTree: BSTree): List[Int] =
  bSTree.fold(List[Int]())((acc, next) => acc :+ next)

toList(testTree) // List(0,1,2,3,4)
```

My implementation above is *O(n²)*. We can improve it to *O(n)* by using a `ListBuffer`, as per @dkim's comment, or we can use `Vector` and then convert to `List` when we're done.

Apart from simply fixing the `toList` method, we might ask why the result of using `fold` to implement `toList` didn't agree with our intuition (giving us a backwards list instead of a forwards list). One might point out that the fold signature for list matches the structure of the `List` class hierarchy.

```
abstract class List[+A] {
  def fold[B](init: B)(step: (A, B) => B): B
}

case object Empty extends List[Nothing] {
  def fold[B](init: B)(step: (A, B) => B): B = init
}

case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A] {
  def fold[B](init: B)(step: (A, B) => B): B =
    step(head, tail.fold(init)(step))
}
```

Notice how the method signature of `fold` matches the class hierarchy, even down to the values that each implementing class holds. (Aside: For purposes of brevity, I am using a very naive implementation of `fold` that is neither efficient nor stack safe. Production implementations should be tail recursive or use a loop and a mutable buffer, but the point is that the method signature would be the same.)

We can do the same for your `BSTree` class, the `fold` signature would be:

```
abstract class BSTree {
  def fold[A](withEmpty: A)(withNode: (A, Int, A) => A): A
}
```

Then `toList` would be `tree.fold(List[Int]())((l, n, r) => l ++ List(n) ++ r)`. But again, use a buffer or `Vector` to get decent performance if you anticipate `tree` being even about 50 entries or so.

Comment: I don't think using a mutable structure is any improvement over reversing the result in the end.

Comment: You're right, if you don't take an immutable copy before returning. Obviously you don't want the mutability to leak out.

Comment: If you don't make a copy, it leaks. If you do, it's the same cost as reversing the list. No need for mutability either way.